# Select all pivotitems and deselect (blank)

Tags: excel, vba, pivotitem

I have a pivot table with multiple fields.  One of the fields is for comments.  When I refresh the table, the comments field is set to (blanks) only.  I have searched for a way to make the pivottable default to not selecting blanks but not luck.

I wrote the code below to uncheck (blanks) and select all other pivotitems. The code works but take more than 5 minutes run.

Any suggestions on how to speed up the code or a better way to deselect (blanks) and select all will be greatly appreciated.

```
`Dim ary As Variant, RVary As Variant
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer
ary = Array("CM PSL", "NM PSL", "CQ PSL", "NQ PSL", "CM Country", "NM Country", "CQ Country", "NQ Country", "QTR Summary", "TY PSL", "TY Country")
RVary = Array("CMRVCS", "NMRVCS", "CQRVCS", "NQRVCS")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
For Each i In ary
Sheets(i).Activate
    For Each j In RVary
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RVCS")
            With .PivotFields(j)
                For k = 2 To .PivotItems.Count
                    .PivotItems(k).Visible = True
                Next k
                .PivotItems(1).Visible = False
            End With
        End With
    Next j
Next i

Erase array1
Erase RVCS

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("CM PSL").Select
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a solution that reduces the runtime to 30 seconds.  Here is the new loop.

```
    For Each i In ary
    Sheets(i).Activate
        For Each j In RVary
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RVCS").PivotFields(j).ClearAllFilters
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RVCS").PivotFields(j)
                .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
            End With
        Next j
Next i
```

Comment: You can make it even faster by 1) Not activating the sheet (just delete that line) and 2) adding the following line before the For Each J line:
PivotTables("RVCS").ManualUpdate = True 
...then add this after the Next J line:
PivotTables("RVCS").ManualUpdate = False

That stops the PivotTable updating until you've made all your changes.

Comment: The answer is good, but you have to be aware of some possible errors. See here for a more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54420639/10908769