# Macro to change the Pivot filter automatically does not work

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot, pivot-table

I have a report with several pivot tables that run off production data, orders and deliveries.  I run it daily and then change the filters in my report to select all of the delivery numbers, and then unselect the blank delivery numbers.

In other words, I'm only selecting those orders that contain a delivery number. If the delivery number is blank, then the order is not set to ship yet.

```
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Del #").CurrentPage = _
        "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Del #")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Del #").CurrentPage = _
        "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Del #")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I want for this to go in and select all of the delivery numbers, except for the blank delivery numbers.

[image: Screen shot]

It seems to fail to select "All", and only has selected what was previously selected the day prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to show every PivotItem except blank ones

If `PivotTables().PivotFields().EnableMultiplePageItems` is set to `True`, then you can not select *all* PivotItems by setting the `PivotFields.CurrentPage` to `="(All)"` (although the macro recorder records only that!).

To select all PivotItems, just use `PivotField.ClearManualFilter` or `PivotField.ClearAllFilters` (on the PivotField, not accidentially on the PivotTable!). Afterwards you can hide (unselect) the blank ones.

```
With WorkSheet.PivotTables(...).PivotFields(...)
    .ClearManualFilter    ' or ClearAllFilters
    If .PivotItems.Count > 1 Then   ' at least 1 has to remain visible
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End If
End With
```

**Error Handling**
At least one PivotItem has to remain visible. You'll get an error, if there are *only* blanks and you try to hide them.
If there are *no* blanks either, then you get an error, which you should catch with `On Error Resume Next`, or you can loop over all items first to check if one of them is called "(blank)". It is not enough to check the last PivotItem's name like `If .PivotItems(.PivotItems.Count).Name = "(blank)"`, as it is not necessarily the last entry.

**Your example** should work with this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Del #")
    .ClearManualFilter
    If .PivotItems.Count > 1 Then   ' at least 1 has to remain visible
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End If
End With
```

Maybe you need to `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").RefreshTable` every day additionally.

## The other way round: How to show only the blank PivotItems

If `EnableMultiplePageItems = True` and one or many were selected, but **not the blank ones**, then `CurrentPage = "(blank)"` raises an error.
You have to enable the blank ones first, either by clearing the filters like above or by making the blanks visible additionally, and then you can select the page with blank ones only:

```
WorkSheet.PivotTables().PivotFields().PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
WorkSheet.PivotTables().PivotFields().CurrentPage = "(blank)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked out great and I only had to make a few changes (not to your code but to what I had that wasn't shown), which was actually good because it helped me learn even more!