# Using an Array to Filter a Pivot Table Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm new to arrays and how to use them correctly. I keep getting `MyArray(i,1) = subscript out of range` and it highlights the rows, where I put in those asterisks.

I want to minimize line count and make it more efficient, so I can pull the same array into different pivot to filter.

```
Sub Macro1()     

Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

    'Populate the array.
    MyArray = Array("I1", "I2", "I3")

    'Filter based off array values
    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
*       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("letters "). _
*       CurrentPage = MyArray(i, 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

My old code that I'm trying to make more efficient is:

```
Sub Macro1()      

    Sheets("NonDomestic").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("letters "). _
        CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With Sheets("NonDomestic").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "dir sales ship cust cot ")

        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotItems("A1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("B1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("C1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("C2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("E1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("F1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("F2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("F3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("F4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("F5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("F6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("F7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("G1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("G2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("G3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("G4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("G5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("H1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("H3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("H4").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("I1").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("I2").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("I3").Visible = False
    End With

On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Are arrays 0- or 1-based? (0-based!) It matters because your array is sized according to I1 and I2, no? SO is not a great tutorial site, so maybe check "vba array" web search results and see if you are doing what you should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CurrentPage` is intended to show only 1 `PivotItem` of your filter.
If you have a list of visible/unvisible `PivotItems`, then set them individually visible, addressing them by their name or by their index.

```
Private Sub PivotFilterTest()
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    myArray = Array("I1", "I2", "I3")
    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("letters ")
    With pf
        .ClearManualFilter
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
            .PivotItems(myArray(i)).Visible = False
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are the man!  I appreciate such a detailed and quick response!

Comment: @Patch Thanks :) And if you get further and hassle with the "blank" page, then please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54420639/10908769